# Kafka Producer From Remote Server

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm developing a streaming API with Apache Kafka version (2.1.0). I have a Kafka cluster and an external server.
The external Server will be producing data to be consumed on the Kafka cluster.

Let's denote the external Server as **E** and the cluster as **C** . **E** doesn't have Kafka installed. I run on it a JAR file to produce messages. Here is the snippet for  **Producer  properties:**

```
properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "bootstrapIp:9092");
properties.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "producer");
```

I set `bootstrapIp` to the Kafka broker IP.

In the cluster side, I start the consumer console using this command:

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server bootstrapIp:9092 --topic T1 --from-beginning
```

I set `bootstrapIp` to the cluster bootstrap server IP.

When running the producer and the consumer on the cluster, it works very fine, but when i run the producer in the external server (**E**) and the consumer in the cluster (**C**) the data not being consumed.

In localhost every thing is working fine also when i run the producer and the consumer in the cluster (**C**) everything is working fine, when running the producer externally i can't consume the data in the cluster.

The ping from cluster(**C**) to  external server (**E**) is working, but i can't see where the problem is exactly.

I am not able to figure out how to consume messages from an external server.

**EDIT**

From the external server (**E**) i telnet the (**bootstrapIp**):
telnet bootstrapIp 9092 and it works, i don't understand the problem

Comment: Did you try pinging from 'E' to 'C' ? I think it might be some DNS issue. Also I will suggest you to configure the Logger in your producer code and run with DEBUG level log.

Comment: Are you sure that the "external" producer can connect and send messages to Kafka? Can you run `$ kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server bootstrapIp:9092 --describe --topic T1`, and share producer logs as well.

Comment: @mrnakumar yes the ping is working from E to C and from C to E

Comment: @mazaneicha this is the problem, the "external" producer  cannot connect to kafka, but when i run the producer and the consumer inside the cluster they can connect

Comment: In your question, you're making a distinction between broker IP and "boostrap server" IP. Are they really different?

Comment: By the way, running Kafka clients on the actual brokers is discouraged

Comment: @mazaneicha no they aren't, they are the same i edited the question

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm trying to run a producer from a remote server and I have the same problem. I'm a noob in kafka. My producer tries to connect to localhost even if I give the ip address of my server.

Answer (score 2):

Tbis works for me:
From server.properties Uncomment

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
```

And

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<HOST IP>:9092
```

Replace  with actual IP. My case:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.75.132:9092
```